# Writing manpages in 20XX

Tags: unix, manpage

I wrote a program, and I'd like to write a manpage for it.

I started to learn Groff, and I really find it awful. The `man` macros are difficult to understand, difficult to use, and a real obstacle to productivity. The `mdoc` macros add a nice "semantic" extension, but they still suffer of limitations which make it incredibly hard. The resulting "code" is poor in maintainability.

Of course I know I can convert any modern markup language (say Markdown) into manpages via `pandoc`, but I dislike the result, and I'm not that fond of adding `pandoc` as dependency of my project, anyway.

Is there a way to obtain a decent manpage from a reasonable markup language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write manpages for the bash and ruby scripts I write.

I format them in [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), which is a popular and simple text format.

Then I use a ruby gem called [ronn](https://github.com/rtomayko/ronn) to process the markdown into groff format with man macros. Ronn can also output html from the same markdown source.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. After checking some alternatives, I decided to go for Asciidoc.

There are many alternatives indeed. For example, check [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/109490/how-do-i-write-man-pages).

I also realized that there's no good answer to this question, given the fact that many tools can be used, and in the end it is just a matter of taste :)
I'll just vote for closing my own question (if anything it will remain as reference).